# Android TextView Height: Not wrapping content

Tags: android, textview, android-xml, word-wrap

I have a strange problem with the most simple task.. Just a TextView with text in it. It is a long string wit
hout new lines. The problem is that the textview does not wrap the content to adjust the height and cuts my text. If I set the height to match_parent I can see the whole text but this is not the idea.

**Edit:**
I also use a custom shrift which I add programmatically.

Here are some pictures:

**Text cut**

[image: Text cut]

**Full text**

[image: Full text]

**And here is the XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

        android:text="@string/one_bedroom_apartment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @Crash_ID try giving the height by yourself like 
android:layout_height="30dp"

Comment: It is perfectly working. just checked; no text cutting

Comment: This is really strange.. Which android version do you use?

Comment: it gives you an alert on your textview. It shouldnt. try to fix it maybe

Comment: The problem isn't with the alert..

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have a similar problem.

Comment: It was long time ago. I don't remember, sorry ;s